File becomes locked during Stream.CopyTo in Azure WebJob
I have an Azure app service (Windows) that I'm developing a continuous, queue-triggered webjob on. This webjob retrieves a file from an Azure storage account file share and attempts to copy the content to a given location. If the file already exists, it's overwritten. Otherwise, a new file is created.
In order to download the file I do the following:
ShareFileClient file = shareDir.GetFileClient($"{list}.dat");
if (!file.Exists())
{
    logger.LogError($"ERROR: Couldn't find {list}.dat file in the file share.");
    return;
}

try
{
    ShareFileDownloadInfo download = file.Download();
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(downloadPath, $"{list}.dat"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
    {
        download.Content.CopyTo(fs);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.LogError($"EXCEPTION: An exception occurred while downloading {list}.dat.{Environment.NewLine}{ex.Message}{Environment.NewLine}{ex.InnerException?.Message ?? ""}");
    return;
}

Take the scenario where the file doesn't already exist in the app service file system. Despite the file being created in the queue-trigger function using statement in the code above, I'm receiving the following exception:

The process cannot access the file 'PATH TO LIST FILE' because it is being used by another process.

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the offending file's size is about 1.5 GB. I've check the app service plan, and it's nowhere near its limits in terms of memory and CPU, so I'm pretty confident that isn't the issue. It seems as if the file lock gets revoked at some point, but I don't understand what's causing it. It should also be noted that these are the directions provided by Microsoft for downloading a file from a storage account file share, found below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.files.shares-readme?view=azure-dotnet

What's informing that guess? This is a 64-bit app service and I'm just grabbing the packages noted in MS docs from Nuget

@PoulBak I would encourage you to do a bit more digging before commenting. The ShareFileClient is connected to the file share. the Content attribute is simply a Stream. This is failing during the Stream.CopyTo operation and the file lock is on the app service file system, not the file share.

This is looking to be another case of a message lease expiring, causing the queue message to be reprocessed. This would also explain why it looked like the queue message was being processed around 4 times. I've modified my code to update the lease and am testing things out.

This turned out to be a problem related to the message lease expiring, causing the queue message to be reprocessed. The following code extends the message lease by 2 hours (arbitrary amount of time to finish work) and keeps the message from being reprocessed too quickly:
QueueClient copyFilesQueueClient = new(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage"), $"{siteName}-copy-list-files");
copyFilesQueueClient.UpdateMessage(queueMessage.MessageId, queueMessage.PopReceipt, queueMessage.Body, new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0));

